# External monitor not working with HDMI

Tags: nvidia, display, hdmi, screen, monitor

I am using a DELL XPS 15 9570 laptop with UBUNTU 18.04 LTS.
When I connect the external screen through HDMI, the screen is not working. I have tried multiple solutions found on internet but any of them worked. However, I borrowed an HDMI-USB converter and the screen was completely functional. To be honest, I do not even know whether the problem is the HDMI port or the NVIDIA drivers.
In case of need, [this is the output of xrandr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4mz1.png)

I have also tried different NVIDIA driver versions. [This is the one I have currently installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKxEg.png)

I can post any extra image needed.

Comment: If the HDMI to USB converter works how can it be the drivers?

Comment: I have an HDMI monitor connected to 20.04.2 LTS. The only thing not working correctly is the sound output (but I use a different solution for that anyway). But what I did note is that I had to set the monitor (a Phillips) to accept HDMI as the input on the monitor setup screen so in my case, not necessarily a Ubuntu issue.

Comment: I started researching about other possibilities just in case. I guess the problem might be that the corresponding HDMI driver was not correctly installed after installing UBUNTU. However, I could not find anything related to it.

Comment: @24601 I also tested the screen in a Windows laptop through HDMI and it was working correctly, so in my case it can't be that issue.

Comment: same issue here :(